# Gstreamer on Yocto

Tags: gstreamer, yocto, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to capture video from logitech c270 webcam from gstreamer in beaglebone-black yocto which is created by core-image-sato. There is a problem that when I use `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! autovideosink` command, I get:

> basesrc gstbasesrc.c::2939:gst_base_src_loop: error: Internal data stream error.

Also, I tried `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! autovideosink` command and gst-launch window was opened, but it showed nothing.

The same procedure with Ubuntu 16.04 is totally successful.

I couldn't find out what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can get debug logs with prepending `GST_DEBUG=9 gst-launch-1.0 ....`. It's better to specify src/sink without relying on "auto" plugins. Last, you can check with `v4l2-ctl --all` which formats/devices are supported.

Comment: Did you try with `autovideosrc` plugin instead of `v4l2src`?

Comment: @PierreOlivier Yes, I did try it, but problem is still the same.

Comment: @Nayfe I've used gst_debug=9, but there were lots of informations and, as I'm beginner in Gstreamer, I couldn't understand how I should analyze them.

Comment: you can pastebin the result and share it here

Comment: @Nayfe It's like infinite loop, always printing new lines until I close it. I feel confused about which lines I should send.

Comment: You can set debug level to less than 9, i.e `GST_DEBUG=3`

Comment: @Nayfe    Here are them: https://pasteboard.co/Heh6RPt.jpg      https://pasteboard.co/Heh7m27.jpg            https://pasteboard.co/Heh7zMX.jpg      by GST_DEBUG=3.  And as you see, its freezing after the last line.

Comment: It seems autovideosink tries to output to X11, and it does not found it? You should try another sink module.

Comment: @Nayfe I've tried all other sink modules and the problem is the same.. Btw, thank you though.

Comment: did you try to test gstreamer sink without the camera, with videotestsrc for example? Did you try to use C270 without gstreamer, maybe look [here](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/boot-scripts/tree/master/tools/software/mjpg-streamer)